# Java - add N distance to string

Tags: java

I am quite new in Java world and I am struggeling with the following problem:

I am currently trying to edit a coding in which, given a string, following changes are made:

- if is uppercase, change it to lowercase and vice versa
- to the corresponding string corresponds another string which is in a distance of N positions

I wrote the following:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public String code(String text, int distance) {
    // cambio mayus <-> minus
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
        char c = sb.charAt(index);

        if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
        } else {
            sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
    }

    // comparison string to ALPHABET
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0, j < ALPHABET.length(); j++) {
            //tiene en cuenta mayusculas y minusculas
            if (sb[i] == ALPHABET[j] && sb[i] == ALPHABET[j].toUpperCase()) {
                // adds the distance
                sb[i] = ALPHABET[j+distance];
            }
        }
    }

    return sb;
}
```

Until now I doubt if is well done and I don't know how to deal with the problem that `ALPHABET` has a circular behaviour, I mean, if the distance N is greater than 26, from 'z', will go again to 'a' This is what I don't know how to express.

How would you do it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "which is in a distance of N positions" -> what do you mean by this?

Comment: why do you check if the character matches one in alphabet and one in alphabet uppercase? should that be `||` instead of `&&`? you can use the modulus operator (`%`) to handle the circular behavior: `ALPHABET[(j + distance) % ALPHABET.length()]`

Comment: Are you trying to make a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you're asking. Is your only problem the circularity of your array? (Note that this code doesn't run)

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, I mean the following: given an input text of 'A' and a distance of 3, the output must be 'd'. Other example: if the input is (y,2), the output will be 'A'. The distance is the characters of the string ```ALPHABET``` between the given in the input and the one that correspond in the output

Comment: @DavidConrad, I want to compare where is the character of the input so that then I can add the distance to assign the new value

Comment: @VGR, yes, you are right. Is not 100% as I need also to exchange uppercase and lowercase

Comment: @JettoMartínez, I know it doesn't work as I don't know if the functionality should be like this. The question I was asking is the combination of answers made by VGR and David Conrad.

Comment: You didn't answer what I asked, though. Why check the character `&&` uppercase? Shouldn't it be `||`?

Comment: @DavidConrad isn't this the way to check wether the string is or not?

Comment: Whether the string is or not WHAT? If you're trying to check if it's uppercase OR lowercase, you need to use OR, not AND. It can't be both.